# No Wifi on new installed Ubuntu, BCM43228

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I newly installed Ubuntu alongside Windows on my laptop and no connection to the internet is available.

Ubuntu Version should be the newest and I am new to Ubuntu and wanted to get some experience in it. I tried e.g. `sudo apt-get update` and other suggested commands but no packages (so every installation doesn't work) were found and connections to some http-resources failed also, because the site couldn't resolve.

Any hints for the solution would be awesome!

If any information is needed, just let me know

Output of `lspci | grep -i network`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
```

Comment: Hans, can you please add the output of `lspci | grep -i network`to your question?

Comment: I edited my question ;)